# How to show count and percentages using prop.table with multiple variables?

Tags: r, percentage

I am struggling with the `prop.table` function, I am trying to get it to display the percentages of each count for the variables. Currently it is only displaying the percentages of the *owner* variables *N* and *Y* within each opinion. I would like it to display the percentage of each *Y* /*N* variable amongst all opinions, so the total of the whole percentage output column is 100.

This is the code I used and the output.

```
hey <- data %>% group_by(opinion, owner) %>% 
  summarize(count = n()) %>% mutate(percentage=prop.table(count)*100)
hey
```

```
   opinion           owner     count      percentage
   <chr>             <chr>     <int>      <dbl>
 1 Agree             N            22       56.4
 2 Agree             Y            17       43.6
 3 Disagree          N             2       16.7
 4 Disagree          Y            10       83.3
 5 Not Sure          N             1       16.7
 6 Not Sure          Y             5       83.3
 7 Strongly Agree    N            57       66.3
 8 Strongly Agree    Y            29       33.7
 9 Strongly Disagree N             1       20  
10 Strongly Disagree Y             4       80
```

Comment: It looks like summarize() has grouped by `opinion`. Putting `ungroup()` between `summarize()` and `mutate()` should give you percentages over the entire column of `counts`.

Comment: `janitor::tabyl()` is also good for this

Comment: Replace `group_by(opinion, owner) %>% summarize(count = n())` with `count(opinion, owner)`. Aside from being more succinct, the result will be ungrouped, avoiding the issue @nahp identified.

Comment: Thanks the first response works from nahp, but I can't seem to get the response from @zephryl to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xtabs` and `cbind` the `proportions`. (Note, that *"`prop.table` is an earlier name, retained for back-compatibility."*)

```
as.data.frame(xtabs(~ owner + opinion, dat)) |> {\(.) cbind(., perc=proportions(.$Freq)*100)}()
#    owner           opinion Freq       perc
# 1      N             Agree   22 14.8648649
# 2      Y             Agree   17 11.4864865
# 3      N          Disagree    2  1.3513514
# 4      Y          Disagree   10  6.7567568
# 5      N          Not Sure    1  0.6756757
# 6      Y          Not Sure    5  3.3783784
# 7      N    Strongly Agree   57 38.5135135
# 8      Y    Strongly Agree   29 19.5945946
# 9      N Strongly Disagree    1  0.6756757
# 10     Y Strongly Disagree    4  2.7027027
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(opinion = c("Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
"Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
"Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
"Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
"Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
"Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
"Disagree", "Disagree", "Disagree", "Disagree", "Disagree", "Disagree", 
"Disagree", "Disagree", "Disagree", "Disagree", "Disagree", "Disagree", 
"Not Sure", "Not Sure", "Not Sure", "Not Sure", "Not Sure", "Not Sure", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
"Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Disagree", "Strongly Disagree", 
"Strongly Disagree", "Strongly Disagree", "Strongly Disagree"
), owner = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), n = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-148L), class = "data.frame")
```